# Zend framework - duplication in translated url

Tags: zend-framework, url, routes, zend-route, zend-translate

I have these URLs

```
cz/kontroler/akce

en/controller/action
```

Is used transatable route and works it like charm. But problem is, that when you will write

```
cz/controller/akce
```

it works as well.

In generally when you have

```
cz/something-in-czech
en/something-in-english
```

which route to someController, will be works still

```
cz/some
en/some
```

because it is really name of controller.

How solve this duplicity content issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a [plugin](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.plugins.html) that uses a preDispatch method. Before the request is executed, you can analyze the url requested and check if the requested language match the language of the params in the url (I mean controller and action). If not, you can redirect the user to the url that is in accord to the given language (basically you'll translate the controller and the action and then redirect the user to the right url).

Comment: I made it similar way. I was suprised that it doesn't controll internal during route and nowhere is write about it in documentation. When I didn't find out by accident I propably would penalize by google.

Comment: @tomasr You can always use the rel="canonical" to tell Google what url you want to be the prefered one.